# Place two buttons side by side in the bottom right corner of a div

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons which I want to place side by side in the lower right corner of the div container.
I tried it like this but the buttons are on the exact same position, so I can only see one of them.

My css code for the button and for the div container:

```
.buttonRight{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: -10px;
margin-right: 4px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.box{
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
padding-top: 10px;
width: 75%;
position: relative;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 60%;
background-color: rgb(204, 38, 38);
border: 2px solid black
}


    <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Preis</th>
    <th>Link</th>
  </tr>
  {{#each items}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{this.name}}</td>
    <td>{{this.price}}</td>
    <td><a href="{{this.link}}">{{this.name}}</a></td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
<a href="add"><button class="buttonRight">Add</button></a>
<a href="remove"><button class="buttonRight">Remove</button></a>
```

Comment: post your HTML as well, I am guessing you applied buttonRight class to both buttons so they overlapped.

Comment: I did that, you're right..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a container for the buttons with exactly same CSS as in the .buttonRight class, and the html + CSS would be something like:

```css
.buttonRight{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: -10px;
margin-right: 4px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
}
body {
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height:300px;
}
.box{
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
padding-top: 10px;
width: 75%;
position: relative;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 60%;
background-color: rgb(204, 38, 38);
border: 2px solid black
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="box">
<div class="buttonRight"><button>click</button><button>click</button></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use flexbox, it's pretty straightforward with it :

```
.box{
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
padding-top: 10px;
width: 75%;
position: relative;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 60%;
background-color: rgb(204, 38, 38);
border: 2px solid black
}

.buttonRight{
position: absolute;
add this ==> display : flex;
and this ==> align-items : flex-end
add this on its childs ==> flex : 0 //if yout want the button width and height to not stretch or shrink
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: -10px;
margin-right: 4px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

Comment: It kinda works, thank you. But there's also a table in my div. I just want the buttons to move to the bottom right, not everything.

Comment: then make a container for your buttons in add the flex properties to it, it should only move your buttons

Answer (score 0):

Run and check this, hope it helps.

```css
.buttonRight{
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
right: 10px
}

.box{
margin: auto;
padding-top: 10px;
min-height:100px;
width: 75%;
position: relative;
background-color: rgb(204, 38, 38);
border: 2px solid black
}
.buttonRight div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="box">
  <table>
  <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Preis</th>
   <th>Link</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>name</td>
   <td>price</td>
   <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
  <div class="buttonRight">
   <a href="#">One</a>
   <a href="#">Two</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```